I can't get nested navigation menus to be shown up by wagtailmenus in wagtail
I use Wagtail CMS with wagtailmenus. Both of them is the latest version. Wagtail is 6.02 and wagtailmenus is 4.0. I would like to use it for main nested navigation bar. I defined the main menu in the cms user interface inline with the philosophy of wagtailmenus. I also let wagtail menus to represent the submenus based on entirely on the page hierarchy. All of my pages live=True and show_in_menus=True so the submenus should appear as well.
Unfortunately, only the top menus are shown up, the res not. I used the code snippet of the wagtail documentation. When I checked item.sub_menu it was always empty.
My homepage:
{% load menu_tags %}
<header>
    ...
    {% main_menu max_levels=2 template="custom_main_menu.html" %}
    ...
</header>

My custom_main_menu.html is:
{% load menu_tags %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Red Sea Boats Holidays</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarScroll" aria-controls="navbarScroll" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-nav-scroll" style="--bs-scroll-height: 100px;">
          {% for item in menu_items %}
            <li class="nav-item {{ item.active_class }} {% if item.has_children_in_menu %} dropdown{% endif %}" >
            <a class="nav-link {{ item.active_class }}" aria-current="page" href="{{ item.href }}" {% if item.has_children_in_menu %} class="nav-link {{ item.active_class }} dropdown-toggle" id="ddtoggle_{{ item.link_page.pk }}" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"{% endif %}>{{ item.text }}</a>
            {% if item.has_children_in_menu %}
                {% sub_menu item template="custom_sub_menu.html" %}
            {% endif %}
          </li>            
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex" role="search">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>

The custom_sub_menu.html is:
{% load menu_tags %}

{% if menu_items %}
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="ddtoggle_{{ parent_page.pk }}">
    {% for item in menu_items %}
        <li class="{{ item.active_class }} {% if item.has_children_in_menu %} dropdown{% endif %}">
            <a href="{{ item.href }}" class="dropdown-item {% if item.has_children_in_menu %} dropdown-toggle" id="ddtoggle_{{ item.pk }}" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"{% endif %}>{{ item.text }}{% if item.has_children_in_menu %} <span class="caret"></span>{% endif %}</a>
            {% if item.has_children_in_menu %}
                {% sub_menu item template=current_template %}
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}

The relevant part of my base.py:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "home",
    "schedule",
    "search",
    "wagtail.contrib.forms",
    "wagtail.contrib.redirects",
    "wagtail.embeds",
    "wagtail.sites",
    "wagtail.users",
    "wagtail.snippets",
    "wagtail.documents",
    "wagtail.images",
    "wagtail.search",
    "wagtail.admin",
    "wagtail",
    "modelcluster",
    "taggit",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "wagtail_modeladmin",
    "wagtailmenus",
    "wagtailmetadata",
    "wagtail.contrib.table_block",
    "wagtail.contrib.styleguide",
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "templates"),
        ],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "wagtail.contrib.settings.context_processors.settings",
                "wagtailmenus.context_processors.wagtailmenus",
            ],
        },
    },
]

the tree of my pages in wagtail hierarchy:
|_Root
  |_Home
    |_Destinations
    |  |___Bali
    |  |___Egypt
    |  |___Philippines
    |
    |_Boats
      |_Andromeda
      |-Cassiopeia

When the html is rendered I see only the top level Destinations and Boats menus but do not see the submenus as a dropdown.
I really do not have idea why the context processor does not populate the sub_menu.
Any help is appreciated.
